# flask with python 3.10 does not import spacy in replit

Tags: python, spacy, replit

I want to import spacy into a flask app running python 3.10 on replit. I am getting no error when I do pip install spacy, i.e. spacy gets installed. However, when I write import spacy in the app.py file, I get the error. It seems like libstdc++.so.6 does not get imported correctly. How should I fix this error? Thanks!

Here is the error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Document-Reading-Virtual-Assistant/app.py", line 6, in <module>
    import spacy
  File "/home/runner/Document-Reading-Virtual-Assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .errors import setup_default_warnings
  File "/home/runner/Document-Reading-Virtual-Assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spacy/errors.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .compat import Literal
  File "/home/runner/Document-Reading-Virtual-Assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spacy/compat.py", line 4, in <module>
    from thinc.util import copy_array
  File "/home/runner/Document-Reading-Virtual-Assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/thinc/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .config import registry
  File "/home/runner/Document-Reading-Virtual-Assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/thinc/config.py", line 2, in <module>
    import confection
  File "/home/runner/Document-Reading-Virtual-Assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/confection/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import srsly
  File "/home/runner/Document-Reading-Virtual-Assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/srsly/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._json_api import read_json, read_gzip_json, write_json, write_gzip_json
  File "/home/runner/Document-Reading-Virtual-Assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/srsly/_json_api.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import ujson
  File "/home/runner/Document-Reading-Virtual-Assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/srsly/ujson/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .ujson import decode, encode, dump, dumps, load, loads  # noqa: F401
ImportError: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
exit status 1"
```

I tried to reinstall different versions of packages without a result.

Comment: I don't think you can install c++ libraries in replit

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought, then how should I fix this error? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You can't fix it in replit? Run your code in a different environment. Such as on your local machine, a VM, Docker, etc?

Comment: I found the error, it was an environment path error. You can close this question, thank you!

Comment: You post an answer yourself to the post and mark that as the accepted one, to help other coming here.